# Save date from QField

Tags: qfield

I started using QField and collected data on the field. I use it with QFieldSync for QGIS.

I have some difficulties to save date on the cloud. It seems there are some errors when I updated the data, in the changes tab on the website for the status I have "error". I don't understand what went wrong, but on my app on android, I have all the last data.

Is it possible to access or save the data from QField without losing them?

Error

> Apply Deltas 16:39:56.678 root INFO Loading project file
> "/tmp/tmpqxr8d6wu/files/PLD_AMO_PU_ANNEXES-BASE_V2_cloud.qgs"...
> 16:40:26.566 root INFO Loading delta file "/io/deltafile.json"...
> 16:40:28.780 qfieldcloud.qgis.apply_deltas INFO Successfully applied
> delta on layer "RDP_XXXXX" [....] Stop QGIS Application 16:42:21.242
> QGSSTDERR WARNING QFSFileEngine::open: No file name specified
> 16:42:21.243 QGSSTDERR INFO Stopping QGIS app… Upload Project
> 16:42:25.949 root INFO Local files list for project "XXXX":

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: For the status it's written "error", wich means according to Qfield "failed to apply to the database."

Comment: I found more inforomations:
Apply Deltas
16:39:56.678 root      INFO     Loading project file "/tmp/tmpqxr8d6wu/files/PLD_AMO_PU_ANNEXES-BASE_V2_cloud.qgs"...
16:40:26.566 root      INFO     Loading delta file "/io/deltafile.json"...
16:40:28.780 qfieldcloud.qgis.apply_deltas INFO     Successfully applied delta on layer "RDP_XXXXX"
[....]
Stop QGIS Application
16:42:21.242 QGSSTDERR WARNING  QFSFileEngine::open: No file name specified
16:42:21.243 QGSSTDERR INFO     Stopping QGIS app…
Upload Project
16:42:25.949 root      INFO     Local files list for project "XXXX":

Comment: You may have better luck posting this to the QField github https://github.com/opengisch/QField/issues